# how can i integrate nexmo with my wordpress site?

Tags: sms

I've been looking for something that will enable me send sms messages from my wordpress site to subscribers to my blog (it's not on wordpress.com. I got the files from wordpress.org and uploaded it to my own server). Finally I came across Nexmo.com. I've signed up but now I don't know where to begin from here. I've had a look at the documentation they provided at nexmo but I don't really understand what to do with it.

Could anyone help me with how i can successfully integrate nexmo with my wordpress site? If it helps I'm using the theme graphene on my site.

Comment: I don't think this belongs here, but it's a bit unclear what you're after, which might affect where it gets migrated. As far as I can tell, Nexmo only provides an API and no pre-built tools, which would make this a straight programming(and not WordPress) question. Or is there a plugin that I'm not seeing?

Comment: umm...well i guess you have a point but i wasn't really sure where to put this. well what i want is that subscribers to my wordpress blog get an sms whenever it gets updated. I had to settle for nexmo.com coz it happened to support the telephone networks that are available in my country. I would've used a carrier url but i couldn't find the ones corresponding to the networks available in my country. Right now what I wanna do is to use nexmo to send sms to my subscribers. I'd like them to subscribe via my wordpress blog.

Answer (score 3):

In my knowledge, there is no available plugin that can do this. This requires custom programming. This can only be done using custom WordPress plugin.

First of all, you would need a subscription form of some kind to get subscriber's mobile number.

The plugin can then integrate with WordPress using one of WordPress hooks such as "save_post" and whenever a new post is published, send messages to all subscribed numbers by calling Nexmo REST API using any available library like "Nexmo-PHP-lib by Darren Whitlen".

https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Great first answer, Manish. Welcome to the site.